# matlab simulation in guide with multiple axis

Tags: matlab, animation, user-interface, axes

I am trying to do a simple simulation of a jumping pogo stick. I have created a GUI in which user can select different graphs to compare velocity, angle... I also made a simulation of the pogo stick swing some pendulums which works fine in its own figure. The problem however is continuously updating the figure in the GUI. As in the GUI figure it only displays the final frame.

Is there some sort of periodic interrupt function I can use in my GUI code that will continuously update the animation? or where can I find some main type of function where I can add code as it waits for the GUI interrupts? any other ideas?

Here is the code running the animation.

```
simulation_on = 1;
for j=2:length(t)
    if simulation_on == 1,
        figure(2);
        clf
        hold on
        scale = 3; %scale the simulation drawing
        framesize = 1;
        foot = [0 0];
        body = [0.01*scale lb*2*scale];
        pbody = [radiusshaft*scale lengthshaft*scale]; %set body width,1 and hight,1
        pfoot = [(foot(1)-body(2)*sin(-ab3set(j))) (foot(2)-body(2)*cos(-ab3set(j)))]; %set x position,1 and Y position,2
        pw1foot = [(pfoot(1)+lengthshaft*sin(ap1set(j))*scale) (pfoot(2)-lengthshaft*cos(ap1set(j))*scale)];
        pw2foot = [(pfoot(1)+lengthshaft*sin(ap2set(j))*scale) (pfoot(2)-lengthshaft*cos(ap2set(j))*scale)];
        pwbody = [0.01*scale 0.01*scale];
        drawing(foot,body,ab3set(j)-pi,framesize,'g');
        drawing(pfoot,pbody,ap1set(j)-pi,framesize,'r');
        drawing(pw1foot,pwbody,ap1set(j)-pi,framesize,'r');
        drawing(pfoot,pbody,ap2set(j)-pi,framesize,'b');
        drawing(pw2foot,pwbody,ap2set(j)-pi,framesize,'b');
        %pause(timestep);
        hold off
    end
end
```

the drawing function just uses `fill()` to draw the figure parameters.

Comment: What you may want is `drawnow`. But what are you using to do the simulation -one of Matlab's ODE functions? Where is this animation code being called from? And you're likely going to get terrible quality flickering animations (or ones that slow down due to memory use) using the code above. You should draw your objects to the figure once and then move them around [using their handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/accessing-object-handles.html). [See this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/animation.html) for some ideas or search Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks a lot. 'drawnow' seems to solve the problem.